# Wrapping an application written with newLISP in a single executable OSX app

Tags: macos, executable, single-file, newlisp

As far as i have found out, it's possible -- and allowed -- to "link" and distribute a newLISP script with the newLISP binary to create a single-file executable. Now i would like to do this for an application using the newLISP gui server, much like the newLISP IDE, that is provided with newLISP. I have some questions related to this:

1. I would like to know what is required to build such an app and wrap it up just like newLISP IDE?
2. I have had a look at the packages contents and it seems, that there is some java-related stuff in there, to use/run the GUI server. So i think, i would require this stuff, too. Am i allowed to distribute it with my application, too?
3. The README i found in the newLISP IDE's package says, that the IDE requires some stuff installed outside the application package. I assume, this is only, because the IDE's lisp script is not linked against the newLISP binary?

thanks!

**UPDATE**

after further investigation of the newLISP-GS "app" i am not sure, if newLISP-GS is not only the GUI server ... ? i am little confused, anyway my question is still: how is it possible to build a single-file executable of a newLISP application including GUI-server and am i allowed to distribute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guiserver.lsp and guiserver.jar files provide the interface between newLISP and the Java system that's installed on the machine.

The newLISP 'IDE' is, as far as I know, simply a longish text script that uses the guiserver.lsp file to interface with Java.

The ramifications of the restrictive GPL licence for distributing newLISP 'applications' has been discussed frequently on the newLISP forums, and you may find more answers and help there.